# Recursive cte avoiding loops

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, recursive, query-performance

I'm trying to write a recursive CTE to explore a workflow system. Unfortunately, I'm getting maximum recursion errors due to loops:

```
with cteActs as
 (
  select a.id as [id], aa.TASKNEXTID as [childid]
  from TASK a
  inner join TASKNEXT aa on a.id = aa.TASKPARENTID
  where a.id != aa.TASKNEXTID
  ),
 cteNext as
(
    select a.*
    from cteActs as a
    where a.id=42
    union all
    select a.*
    from cteActs as a
    inner join cteNext as n on a.id = n.childid
    )
select * 
from cteNext
```

The table `TASK` is a list of tasks whereby 42 is "Start job" for example. `TASKNEXT` links 42 to possible subtasks back in the `TASK` table. e.g. it may link 42 to 43 which may be "Find materials" e.g.

```
ID, name, childID
42, Start job, 43
42, Start job, 44
43, Find materials, 200
44, Report to boss, 201
201, Discuss with boss, 202
202, Receive payment, 44
```

I think the recursion is dying because 44>201>202>44 creates a loop the query doesn't escape from. How can I allow for this? Most of the examples/tutorials I read assume a strict parent>child relationship, where a child can never be the parent of something in its own higher tree.

What I'm trying to get to is a distinct list of `TASKS` that originate from flows starting at task 42, or wherever I choose.

---

This is iteration 2 which may work, but runs so slow:

```
  select a.id as [id], aa.ACTIONACTIVITYID as [childid]
   into #temp
  from TASK a
  inner joinTASKNEXT aa on a.id = aa.TASKPARENTID
  where a.id != aa.TASKNEXTID    
  create clustered index [hello] on #temp (ID ASC)
  create nonclustered index [hello2] on #temp (childid ASC)
  ;
with cteNext as
(
    select a.*, 
    cast(',' + cast(a.ID as varchar(10)) + ',' as varchar(max)) as Path,
    0 as [cyc]
    from #temp as a
    where a.id=42
    union all
    select a.*,
    n.Path + cast(a.ID as varchar(10)) + ',',
         case when n.Path like '%,'+cast(a.ID as varchar(10))+',%' 
           then 1 
           else 0 
         end as [cyc]
    from #temp as a
    inner join cteNext as n on a.id = n.childid
    where n.cyc = 0
    )

select   id, childid
from cteNext
where cyc =0
```

[Execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B14NAtwwg)

Comment: Not an identical duplicate question but it is related. [CTE Running in Infinite Loop](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16111/cte-running-in-infinite-loop). You could modify one of the answers to make your recursion terminate when a loop is found. Use the same technique used in the answer to build a string representing the loop path and remove `where Cycle = 1` from the main query and you should have what you are looking for, I guess? Look at the second answer, not the accepted one.

Comment: I think that works, I refactored my code and tried at a sub flow than I know involves a loop and just half a dozen tasks. However for task 42 (the biggest) it's taking forever to execute. 32minutes and counting as I type.

Comment: Your performance could probably be improved by putting the result for `cteActs ` in a temp table and use that temp table instead of the CTE in the recursive part of the query. As you have it now `cteActs`is evaluated a lot, I think once for each invocation of the recursive part of the query.  . Proper indexing of the temp table will also help.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson is right, but you may find the limiting factor to be that the recursive part of an rCTE is always run serially. Check out this article for alternatives: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2015/04/07/re-inventing-the-recursive-cte.aspx

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I think the data is just too complex, running a select * and watching the path column change as I scroll it's running the right ragged and never getting back up to the left most tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the best result I've managed to come up with is adding the following improvements
- optimising the queried table (creating a new temporary table with suggested indexes)
- adding a path element to check I'm not revisiting an existing part of the path
- adding a depth counter as a limiter. This does however mean I'm consciously choosing not to have the full result set

```
  select a.id as [id], aa.ACTIONACTIVITYID as [childid]
   into #temp
  from TASK a
  inner join TASKNEXT aa on a.id = aa.TASKPARENTID
  where a.id != aa.TASKNEXTID

  create clustered index [hello] on #temp (ID ASC)
  create nonclustered index [hello2] on #temp (childid ASC)
  ;
  drop table #temp2;
with cteNext as
(
    select a.*, 
    cast(',' + cast(a.ID as varchar(10)) + ',' as varchar(max)) as Path,
    0 as [cyc], 0 as [depth]
    from #temp as a
    where a.id=42
    union all
    select a.*,
    n.Path + cast(a.ID as varchar(10)) + ',',
         case when n.Path like '%,'+cast(a.ID as varchar(10))+',%' 
           then 1 
           else 0 
         end as [cyc], n.depth+1 as [depth]
    from #temp as a
    inner join cteNext as n on a.id = n.childid
    where n.cyc = 0 and n.depth <=11
    )

select *
into #temp2
from cteNext
where cyc =0
```

The initial purpose of this data is "fluffy", I'm generating a graph-map out of it to show our workflows so a limited depth is fine in the first instance at least. But better answers accepted if anyone has any

Comment: I see a `varchar(max)` in your SQL statement. I my experience, SQL Server seems to operate slower on `varchar(max)` columns than a `varchar(xxxx)` column even though the data content is the same. Based upon the length of your IDs and limiting depth, you might get faster performance limiting your varchar to a specified length just long enough to include the longest IDs and delimiters.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue when building an overview of our database. I wrote a CTE to recursively follow foreign key references to a given base table, but ran into infinite loops in multiple places. I like the idea of keeping a path element to allow cutting off those loops.